# Why am I getting an "undefined function" error for a function I wrote?

Tags: matlab, fibonacci

I have written this to determine the n-th Fibonacci number:

```
function f=fibfun(n)

if n>2
  f=fibfun(n-1)+fibfun(n-2);
else
  f=1;
end
```

It should work but it doesn't. If I type `fibfun(10)` then the answer should be 55. But all I get is:

> **Undefined function 'fibfun' for input arguments of type
>   'double'.**

What does this mean? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that MATLAB can't find your function - the directory where you saved the file fibfun.m should either be the current directory or defined in your MATLAB path.

Comment: I don't get it. I saved the .m file on the Desktop. Where should I save it or what should I do now?

Comment: If you saved to the Desktop, make sure the desktop is your current working directory. Type `cd` at the command prompt to check what folder MATLAB is actually in.

Comment: As mentioned either cd or pwd will give you your current working directory. I'd put the file fibfun.m in that directory to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is on your current path.

Use:

```
addpath(genpath('/path/to/file/'));
```